# Adding high frequency noise to images in matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, signal-processing, noise-generator

The function `imnoise` adds noise to the image. How can I add only high frequency noise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

High frequency noise in appears mainly as "salt and pepper" noise. So to introduce this kind of noise, pick N pixels at random and change their intensities randomly. The randomness implicitly does the job of a high pass filter, because it is unlikely that many neighbouring pixels will be picked among the N.

Comment: Salt and pepper noise is high frequency, but it is not the only kind of high frequency noise. This may work, but it depends what the OP really needs.

Comment: @shoelzer: Agree with you on that, although salt and pepper noise is probably the most "frequently" occuring high frequency noise in images and pretty easy to simulate.

Answer (score 1):

If you generate noise samples with a flat spectrum (white noise), it will contain all frequencies. Then you can filter that noise to shape it any way you want. For high frequency noise, you would want a high pass filter.

Comment: +1: But the noise doesn't have to be uniform... all it has to be is white.

Comment: @EitanT True, but if the noise is uniform I think it's easier to design a filter to get the result you want.

Comment: Shaping the spectral density has nothing to do with the distribution of an individual noise sample. The distribution of each sample affects the values of the noise samples, while the spectral density refers to the way the noise power is distributed among the frequencies.

Comment: @EitanT Now I get your point. I said "uniform distribution", but what I meant was "uniform frequency distribution". I'll update the answer.

Comment: I believe both `rand` and `randn` give a flat spectrum.

Comment: @EitanT Yes, they do. Are you implying that "uniform frequency distribution" is not correct? If so, I don't understand.

Comment: I'm not saying that, although I've never encountered references to flat spectra with the term "uniform". I've just suggested these two functions to expand your answer.